# Rounding a number from a Data Extension that has multiple decimals

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, einstein-recommendations

I have a personalization field that reads from our data extension to show how many purchases have been made from the previous month. The DE I get with over 28k people doesn't shorten the decimal points so I get numbers with 6 decimal places. I'm trying to get the %%totalpurchases%% to show two decimal places.

[image]

When I have that, the test shows up as 400.000000. I want it to just show two decimal places. Can someone tell me what code I need to use/where I need to put it? Noob here, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need here is the AMPscript function **[FormatNumber](https://ampscript.guide/formatnumber/)**. I would also recommend not using 'naked' personalization strings in your email and instead utilize AttributeValue for better error handling.

So something like:

```AMpscript
%%[ 
  SET @totalPurchases = AttributeValue("totalpurchases")
  SET @finalTotal = FormatNumber(@totalPurchases,"#0.00")
]%%

%%=v(@finalTotal)=%%
```

Which should take `400.000000` and format it to `400.00` instead.